# My pyecharts doesn't have module named 'pyecharts.engine'

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want to get a solution about 'No module named 'pyecharts.engine''
It has a ModuleNotFoundError

use pip to install the latest pyecharts

```
from pyecharts.engine import create_default_environment

env=create_default_environment("html")
```

[image]

Comment: what is the name of script?

Comment: Show us the output of `print(pyecharts.__file__)`.

Comment: the output is a path
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyecharts\__init__.py

Comment: sorry,I can't understand what you mean.script???